# Elasticsearch autocompletion mapping and suggestion with mongoDB

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an issue with the autocompletion feature of elastic search.
It is working with my postgresql mapping but not with my mongodb one. Maybe it is because my completion field is not a primary one.

Here is the mapping :

```
{
    "mappings" : {
      "customer" : {
        "properties" : {
          "cd" : {
            "properties" : {
              "EAN" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "ab" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "ad3" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "cc" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "cit" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "civ" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "ctry" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "dob" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "ew" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "fn" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "lvst" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "mn" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "completion"
              },
              "pc" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "pdc" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "stat" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "tb" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "zc" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "cid" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "off" : {
            "properties" : {
              "ol" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "cnt" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  },
                  "desc" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "ed" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "ot" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  },
                  "sc" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  },
                  "sd" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "title" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "rec" : {
            "properties" : {
              "rc" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "rl" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "rst" : {
            "properties" : {
              "pc" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "pl" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "sh" : {
            "properties" : {
              "cnt" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "res" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "ttl" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "date" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "pl" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  },
                  "sta" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }'
```

and this is my query :

```
curl -X POST localhost:9200/retail_crm_demo/_suggest -d '
{
  "retail_crm_demo" : {
    "text" : "du",
    "completion" : {
      "field" : "name"
    }
  }
}'
```

I have another issue, the river is crashing when a field with completion type is trying to save null data, do you know how to avoid this problem ?

Thanking you in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Would you explain, how and when "river is crashing"? I can store a record in your index data:

```
POST /retail_crm_demo/customer
{
    "pc" : "pc1"
}
```

and I have no problem.